# Remove some part of an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

There is an array lut_addresses[] of type int. There are some calculations for a variable table_ptr which is also an int and represents the new base of the array. Now i want to assign lut_addresses[] values beginning from the index table_ptr till the last index to the array lut_addresses[] so that **initial values till table_ptr are deleted and value at table_ptr is present at 0th index of lut_addresses[]**. How can i do it without changing lut_addresses to an arraylist?

Pseudo code:

```
A()
{
   int lut_addresses[] = new int[2048];
   // assign values upto a cetain index
   B(lut_addresses);
};
B()
{
   int table_ptr=0;
   //calculate table_ptr;
   // assign lut_addresses[] values from index table_ptr till (lut_addresses.length-1)  
}
```

Comment: to which the values of lut_addresses need to be assigned

Comment: See my edit -- `System.arraycopy` is the best choice for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing that comes to mind would be to use [System.arraycopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29).

> Copies an array from the specified source array, beginning at the
>   specified position, to the specified position of the destination
>   array.

Comment: Just to clarify, every way to do this in Java would be equivalent to an array copy.  You can't directly manipulate pointers in Java like you could in C or C++.

Answer (score 1):

You could either

- Use a `for` loop that runs over the desired indices, assigning the elements one at a time, or
- Use the `System.arraycopy` method, which copies a given number of elements starting at a given offset in one array to a given offset in another array.

Based on your later edits, I should point out that **`System.arraycopy` correctly handles overlapping source and destination regions,** making it an excellent choice for you.

Comment: I maybe wrong but this method won't remove the elements, and i will get the array with correct elements till index `lut_addresses.length-table_ptr-1` and the remaning elements will remain as they were at their original place.
E.g if `lut_addresses[]=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}`, i will get `lut_addresses[]={4,5,6,7,8,9,10,8,9,10}`

Comment: You keep changing the question, man, this is ridiculous. It used to say something about assigning part of an array, then about copying elements, now it's about removing part of an array. I'm out.

Comment: I am trying something in my project. Thats why so many changes. Hope you don't mind

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = startIndex; i < 2048; i++) {
  lut_addresses[i] = newValue;
}
```

Comment: I haven't seen any other arrays in your question. But you may just place anything you want instead of `newValue`. For example `lut_addresses[i] = source[j]`. You'll need to increment `j` as well of course. But for this task `System.arraycopy()` would be more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change an array's size once it's allocated, but you can store in a variable the size of the "used" part (this is close to what `ArrayList` does internally). So, you could use `System.arraycopy()` to copy some part of one array into other and use a new `int` variable to store the size of the filled in part. Then, when you iterate, use that variable instead of `lut_addresses.length` as the upper iteration limit.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use an [IntBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/IntBuffer.html). from the documentation :

> Relative bulk put methods that transfer contiguous sequences of ints
>   from an int array or some other int buffer into this buffer

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct method to directly get the specified element as in ArrayList, so you have to first loop to search element and then replace each element after this with (index -index of searched element).

Answer (score 0):

you can use `System.arraycopy` that in built-in `java`  standard, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29